# Android: package-related intents not fired

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I'm developing a launcher application, I just added a broadcast receiver I will use to update the app list. I initially tried to receive `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` as they seemed enought for the job, however none where fired so I added all other package-related actions I deemed useful and tried to register for them both in the activity:

```
val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED)
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL)
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)
        val rec = AppsInstallationsReceiver()
        registerReceiver(rec, intentFilter)
```

and manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".core.installed_apps.AppsInstallationsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The receiver itself is nothing special:

```
class AppsInstallationsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

turns out I only receive `PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED` and only if it's registered in the manifest.
Now this is good enought, but I need a way to know when new apps are installed. Since this is a launcher app this feature is critical. Why am I not receiving anything? the activity of course still exists the background since it is used as launcher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware about the [Implicit Broadcast Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) introduced from Android 8.0 and above.

The broadcasts you registered come under the catergory of **restricted broadcasts** (except `ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED`). So, you won't receive these events when you register the actions from manifest. So, remove the receiver entry from manifest.

The alternative solution to this would be to register these broadcasts programatically - ***which you have already done***.

**The only thing missing here is to add `intentFilter.addDataScheme("package")` before registering the receiver.**

Hoping this should resolve your issue.